# sudo command behaviour difference with the -i flag

Tags: shell, unix, escaping, sudo

I intend to write a shell wrapper for the `sudo` command together with the full login context of the root account. I encountered the issue that the dollar character disappeared or interpreted somewhere if I invoked the `sudo` command with the `-i` flag.

When I execute the command `sudo -n /bin/printf "%s\n" '$a'` I get as output:

```
$a
```

When I execute the command `sudo -i -n /bin/printf "%s\n" '$a'` I get an empty line as output.

For the second case I was expecting the same output as for the first command. Am I wrong in my expectation?
If yes, what is the appropriate way to escape the dollar character to match the output of the first command?

Comment: `Am I wrong in my expectation?` Yes. Think about how shells parse the commands you give them. In the case of your sudo example your current shell parses each token. Meaning it removes the quote marks. It then passes `/bin/printf`, `%s\n`, `$a` to the sudo command which passes them to the shell it starts. That shell then expands the `$a` since it is no longer quoted.

Comment: Thanks! Please, would you answer my second question too because you answered yes for my first question? If it is not possible to quote the dollar character at all, you may want rather confirming this fact.

Answer (score 0):

From [`man sudo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html)

> **`-i, -‐login`**
>
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password
> database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-
> specific resource files such as `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.login`
> will be read by the shell.  If a `command` is    specified, it is passed
> to the shell as a simple `command` using the **`-c`** option.  The `command`
> and any `args` are    concatenated, separated by spaces, after escaping
> each    character (including white space) with a backslash (`‘\’`)
> except for alphanumerics, underscores, hyphens, and    dollar signs.

So `sudo /bin/printf "%s\n" '$a'` runs printf directly with two arguments (`%s\n` and `$a`) and printf doesn't know anything about shell variables, therefore prints them unexpanded.

On the other hand:

```
sudo -i /bin/printf "%s\n" '$a'
```

Forks a new shell (the user's login shell) and then passes the command and the args. Characters »except for alphanumerics, underscores, hyphens, and    dollar signs are escaped«. So you end up with sudo executing the following:

```
/bin/sh -c '/bin/printf %s\n $a'
```

The shell then executes the command

```
/bin/printf %s\n $a
```

which means it will expand the parameter before passing it to printf.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to quote the $a that the printf would print $a?

Comment: @user23680159 yes it is possible, don't pass `-i`: `sudo /bin/printf "%s\n" '$a'` already does what you want (as you have shown in your question)